# Cannot find turtlebot3_gazebo on ROS2 humble on 22.04

Tags: navigation, ros-humble

I am following this tutorial

https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-nav2-tutorial/

Although I installed the required packages,

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-navigation2 ros-humble-nav2-bringup ros-humble-turtlebot3*
```

I get this error

```
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py
Package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found: "package 'turtlebot3_gazebo' not found, searching: ['/opt/ros/humble']"
```

here is an excerpt of my variables

```
ROS_HOSTNAME: rosmaster
ROS_IP: 192.168.1.84
ROS_MASTER_URI: http://rosmaster:11311
ROS_DOMAIN_ID: 1
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY: 0
RMW_IMPLEMENTATION: 
TURTLEBOT3_MODEL: waffle
GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH: :/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
-----------------------------------------
ROS_VERSION=2
SESSION_MANAGER=local/pi-ros-2:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2303,unix/pi-ros-2:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2303
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
ROS_IP=192.168.1.84 
VNCDESKTOP=pi-ros-2:1 (pi)
AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/humble
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages:/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://rosmaster:11311
ROS_HOSTNAME=rosmaster
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/humble/opt/rviz_ogre_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/humble/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/humble/lib
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=:/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models

PATH=/opt/ros/humble/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    ROS_DISTRO=humble
```

please help me out, this is quiet frustrating as a learning curve

thanks

[edit]
from the video tutorial , I try to simply run gazebo, and it is just not there at all

```
pi@pi-ros2:~/WORK$ gazebo
gazebo: command not found
pi@pi-ros2:~/WORK$ sudo find / -name gazebo
[sudo] password for pi: 
/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_manipulation_description/gazebo
/home/pi/WORK/bookros2_ws/src/ThirdParty/tiago_robot/tiago_description/gazebo
/home/pi/WORK/bookros2_ws/src/ThirdParty/pmb2_robot/pmb2_description/gazebo
/home/pi/WORK/bookros2_ws/src/ThirdParty/pal_gripper/pal_gripper_description/gazebo
/home/pi/WORK/bookros2_ws/src/ThirdParty/hey5_description/gazebo
```

[edit]
I created an issue on github

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3774

I created another similar issue, as I follow tutorials from F.M Rico's book(Robot programming with ROS2)

https://github.com/fmrico/book_ros2/issues/23

is humble maintained for gazebo and navigation at all ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3766

"So there's a dependency missing in gazebo-land on ARM64 which is blocking everything from gazebo ros to turtlebot then to us. So unfortunately there's really nothing we can do about it here, but I'd recommend following up in that ticket if you wanted to help fix the issue. Else, building from source is your best bet. The issue isn't much to do with nav2_bringup as much as nothing in gazebo classic will work for you on ARM without compilation."

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have turtlebot3_gazebo package. Please check this link and install turtlebot3_gazebo package. Don't forget to select your $ROS_DISTRO.

Link: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/

```
export TURTLEBOT3_GAZEBO=burger
cd ~/turtlebot3_ws && source install/setup.bash
ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_word.launch.py
```

Comment: Unable to locate package turtlebot3_gazebo

Comment: the tutorial AND the video clearly states to install the aforementioned packages https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idQb2pB-h2Q&t=4s

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not install Turtlebot3 Packages, you should go for the Gazebo Turtlebot3 link to install libraries for that, Turtlebot3 in real and in simulation has some differences, which you should learn from the links.

Go on TurtleBot3 Gazebo Link and create pkg accordingly and you should be good to go.

Link to TurtleBot3 Gazebo Setup - https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/

Link for TurtleBot Setup - https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/

Comment: I dont see anything about package installation
also I use ros2 not ros

Comment: tried to compile the git repo, I get
'By not providing "Findgazebo.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project ...' error

Comment: Findgazebo.cmake means your Gazebo was not installed properly.

Comment: I installed Foxy, and updated the question with the details, humble has no gazebo packages